# What are the risks of redirecting my email with Google Domains?

Tags: email, google, protonmail

I have bought a domain from [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com). One of the features they offer is to [redirect all email sent to that domain](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251241?hl=en) to any other email address of my choice. Now I'm wondering; is it secure and private?

1. How secure is using this service? Can Google read the content of the incoming emails if they redirect them for me?
2. Is it safer to let another site handle the email address(es) instead? For example, ProtonMail offer the possibility to [receive all email sent to a domain I own](https://protonmail.com/support/knowledge-base/custom-domain-support/). How does this option compare to telling Google to redirect the emails to my ProtonEmail account?

Comment: Unless everyone who sends you email uses encryption, your email is exposed. Email is a "store and forward" service. Note the word "store" and then "forward". Your email can exist on more than one server on its path to your inbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any email service is processing mail, then there is a possibility that they can "read" the emails. That goes for ProtonMail, too.

The only way to avoid the risks is to have end-to-end encryption of the email content. Email has never meant to be secure from the email handling infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) That's exactly my question, is Google "processing" my email? Or is there some sort of DNS redirect going on?

Comment: The link you provided shows that the DNS MX record points to Google servers. So they process it.